# How can I read scriptduration from the below scope variable?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

```
       {
        "errorMessage": "",
        "instructionIdWithInScript": 1,
        "screenShotFilePath": "/204/1574/screenshots/112186/1.jpg",
        "scriptDuration": "00:01:45",
        "automationDriverName": "Selenium-WebDriver",
        "screenShotFileSize": "277.830078125",
        "screenShotStatus": 28304,
        "value": "",
        "command": "open",
        "scenarioOrder": 1,
        "instructionResult": "Pass",
        "scenarioResult": "Pass",
        "scriptName": "01_copy of SearchBookProduct_WIP",
        "scriptOrder": 1,
        "scriptResult": "Pass",
        "scriptRowCount": 0,
        "scenarioDuration": "00:09:29",
        "scriptDisplayOrder": 1,
        "scenarioName": "Amazon",
        "dataFileName": null,
        "target": "http://www.amazon.com/http://www.amazon.com/http://www.amazon.com/http://ww…zon.com/http://www.amazon.com/http://www.amazon.com/http://www.amazon.com/",
        "globalInstructionSequesnce": 1,
        "scriptIterationOrder": 0,
        "instructionDuration": "00:00:15",
        "dataFilterDesc": null,
        "selected": false,
        "downloadSelect": false
    }
```

I am getting below error when I write `$scope.metaInfo.scriptDuration`.
cannot read property "scriptDuration" undefined.

I edited my question with correct info..

Comment: Why do you have `metaInfo` there?

Comment: I am getting that object info into $scop.metaInfo like this "  $scope.metaInfo = $scope.ssLog[0]; "

Comment: Try `$scope.scriptDuration`

Answer (score 0):

You can access this way if `$scope.metaInfo` is array and right in my case.

```
$scope.metaInfo["scriptDuration"]
```

And if its object then

```
$scope.metaInfo[0].scriptDuration
```

Regards.

Comment: Mark as answered if this does help you. :)

Comment: No , Its did not helped me . Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post exact object that you are assigning to `metainfo` variable ? Also check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I edited my question, please up vote, I don't know why someone down voted it.

Comment: review answer once if it still does not help you then my bad.

Comment: Still having same issue Narola. Thank you for your valuable Time.